# cakephp auth component is not working

Tags: cakephp, authentication

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $uses = array('User', 'Feed', 'Author', 'Comment', 'Tag', 'SingleArticle', 'Category');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('signup');
    }

    public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => array(

            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authError' => "you can't access that page",
            'authenticate' => array(

                'Form' => array(// THIS IS WHERE YOU CHANGE THE DEFAULT FIELDS
                    'fields' => array('email' => 'email', 'pwd' => 'pwd'),
                      'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }  
 public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'mind'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('login failed');
            }
}
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
this is my userscontroller.php.    

my appcontroller.php 
  public $components = array('Auth', 'RequestHandler');
    public $pageTitle;

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
my user.php 

<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';
    var $useTable = 'fvf_users';

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data['User']['pwd'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['pwd'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data['User']['pwd']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

please help me,my login page not worked.it will redirected to the same login page only.
i used the password hasing for blowfish method. please help me.thanks in advance.
which part is mistake in my code.what is the default password encryption method in cakephp.

Cakephp LOGIN not working...:(

Answer (score 0):

Your `fields` array in config is incorrect. Assuming you db fields are `email` and `pwd`. The array needs to be `'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'pwd')`.  Your login form field names would also be `email` and `pwd`.